# Masked array from list of one-element masked arrays: Cannot convert masked element to a Python int

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I want to create a 1d masked array from a list of one-element (0d) masked arrays using `numpy.ma`. This works as expected if the values are not masked, it does not in the other case:

```py
import numpy.ma as ma
ma.MaskedArray([ma.masked_array(data=-99, mask=False), ma.masked_array(data=-99, mask=False)])
ma.MaskedArray([ma.masked_array(data=-99, mask=True), ma.masked_array(data=-99, mask=True)])
```

The second commands produces

```
numpy.ma.core.MaskError: Cannot convert masked element to a Python int.
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour? Do I need to manually extract the data and the masks?

Comment: Would `ma.concatenate` help? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.concatenate.html

Comment: @slothrop With `ma.concatenate` I get a `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`, however, this triggered a further search and with that, I found `ma.stack` which seems to work. So thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry about that but glad you got there in the end!

Comment: For interest, how is your requirement different to `ma.array([-99,-99], mask=[True,True])`

Comment: @user19077881 I got a list of masked arrays as a result of a list comprehension, which I wanted to convert to a masked array. So the data and mask part were separated into different objects. Yes, I guess I would have had to convert my problem to the structure you proposed if I had not found a solution.

Comment: I suspect there's a bug in `MaskedArray`.  The first, with `False` for both elements runs.  It's the `True` mask that's giving problems. But as long as `stack` works,..

Comment: The fact that they are 0d, scalar arrays also contributes to the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, looks strange indeed. I will check the numpy repo again and will file a bug report if needed.